# Excel: How can I replace cell with result of hyperlink formula that is dependent on said cell to work?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, hyperlink

I've got this situation:

```
-|____A___|_________________B________________|_____C______|______D_____|
1| Title1 | =HYPERLINK($C$1 & A1 & $D$1; A1) | URL Part 1 | URL Part 2 |
2| Title2 | =HYPERLINK($C$1 & A2 & $D$1; A2) |            |            |
```

This causes the B cells, in this case, to have working hyperlinks to the complete URL with the titles in the A cells. Now, what I want to do is replace the A cells with the B cell. This is, of course, a problem though as the HYPERLINK function in the B cells are dependent on the A cells that I want to replace. This is the result I'm looking for:

```
-|_____________________A____________________|_B_|_____C______|______D_____|
1| =HYPERLINK($C$1 & Title1 & $D$1; Title1) |   | URL Part 1 | URL Part 2 |
2| =HYPERLINK($C$1 & Title2 & $D$1; Title2) |   |            |            |
```

or just:

```
-|___________________A_______________|
1| =HYPERLINK(Complete link; Title1) |
2| =HYPERLINK(Complete link; Title2) |
```

This wouldn't be a big issue if it was just these two rows but I have over 50 rows like this so a quicker method would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but it seems likely you would be creating a circular reference so you will need to be careful.

I would recommend using a "helper" row to accomplish what you are looking for. If its a one time change have the formula in this column produce what you need possibly with a ' to prevent the hyperlink from being executed. From there copy and paste values over what is in column A.

I hope this helps,
Brad

Comment: I edited the post a bit to hopefully make it clearer. The problem with just copying the values of the result of the formula is that it doesn't create a hyperlink but acts just like the original titles.